# Generic extension method for various types having the same properties

Tags: c#, generics

I am wondering, is it possible to create an extension method that will work with a set of different types provided they have the same property? 
For example:

```
public static T GetObjectByIdOrName<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Mapping mapping) where T : IType1, IType2, IType3
    {
        return collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == mapping.ObjectId || x.Name == mapping.ObjectName);
    }
```

All Types have the Id and Name properties so I hoped this would be possible - however, the compiler is telling me that there is an ambiguous reference between Type1.Id and Type2 Id...

Is there any way to implement this? 
(I cannot create a common base for them)

Comment: Are these classes under your control?

Comment: That constraint means the type has to implement all 3 interfaces.  If they all expose the same properties then it doesn't know which interface it should go through in the case that any of the properties are implemented explicitly.

Comment: can you refactor to make each interface use one base interface?

Comment: @Colin and rest of guys - sadly, making them all inherit from one is not an option for me

Comment: @Bartosz In that case the best you could do is create 3 overloads for each interface.  That or use dynamics.

Comment: @Bartosz  why not?  do the interfaces come from an external assembly?

Comment: @SamIam - yes, this is not my code

Comment: @juharr - Dynamics you say... Not sure how, could you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: @Bartosz - I actually included use of "dynamic" in my answer.

Comment: Something like `public static dynamic GetObjectByIdOrName(this IEnumerable collection, Mapping mapping)`.  Note that's going to push your compile time type checking to the run time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fairly easy given proper code design. Just have them share a common interface.

```
public interface IBase
{
    object Id{ get; set; }
    string Name{ get; set; }
}

public interface IType1 : IBase{}
public interface IType2 : IBase{}

public static T GetObjectByIdOrName<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Mapping mapping) where T : IBase
{
    //... get T.Id or T.Name
}
```

Otherwise, since there is no shared implementation implicit in the design, you can clumsily assume the properties will be there using dynamic.

```
public static object GetObjectByIdOrName(this IEnumerable collection, Mapping mapping)
{
    return collection.Cast<dynamic>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == mapping.ObjectId || x.Name == mapping.ObjectName);
}
```

Comment: `IType1` and `IType2` come from an external project

Comment: @Bartosz Just be aware that dynamics will open you up to run time type errors that would have been caught at compile time without them.  Also there's a bit of a hit to performance when using them.

Comment: Also that dynamic method could still use Linq `return collection.Cast<dynamic>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == mapping.ObjectId || x.Name == mapping.ObjectName);`  As it is it will not compile because not all paths return.  (it needs a `return null;` at the end).